# estimating a derivative at a specific point

Tags: calculus

So let's say I have a differential equation:

$$\frac{df(t)}{dt} = \frac{2-f(t)}{5}$$

I was wondering how do I integrate this between $t=0$ and let's say $t=4$. Ideally, I want an equation that will tell me the value of $f(t)$ dependent on the change of $t$.

I would appreciate if someone could explain how to do this or point me in the right direction.

Thanks!

Comment: That means a differential equation?

Comment: this is a differential equation with the solution $$f(t)=2+Ce^{-t/5}$$ do you mean that?

Comment: yes! is there any way you could explain to me how to get to that point? or point me in the right direction with reading?

Comment: This is a [Separable Differential Equation](http://tutorial.math.lamar.edu/Classes/DE/Separable.aspx).

Comment: You can read about solving separable ODEs [here](http://tutorial.math.lamar.edu/Classes/DE/Separable.aspx)